# Bottom Navigation desaparece

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, navigationview, bottombar

Tengo un menu bajo el cual uso con jetpack compose y navigationview para la interacción pero cuando cambio de fragment o uso el botón de regreso. Este desaparece teniendo que volver a ejecutar la aplicación para poder volver a aparecer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben como puedo corregir este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

comparto mi código que tengo en el mainactivity donde hago la union de ambos menus y configuro la funcionalidad del bottom navigation.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
    private var uslog = ""
    private var rest = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        menu()
        conexion()
        rest = intent.getStringExtra("acceso").toString()
    }

    private fun menu(){
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.inicio,
                R.id.evolucion,
                R.id.rutinas,
                R.id.comidas,
                R.id.planalimentario
            ), binding.drawerLayout  //agrega el menu drawer al toolbar
        )
        //se agregar el home al fragment main
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

        //Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        //Bottom Navigation
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        //DrawerLayout
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    private fun conexion() {
        //recibimos datos desde login con bundle
        uslog = intent.getStringExtra("nombre").toString()
        //cambia el nombre de usuario por el que ingresa en el menu de navegación
        val lateral: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView)
        val headerView: View = lateral.getHeaderView(0)
        val navUsername: TextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.titulouser)
        navUsername.text = uslog
        reply()
    }

    private fun reply() {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bienvenido: $uslog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        bundle.putString("nomper", uslog)
        bundle.putString("tipus",intent.getStringExtra("perfil").toString())
        bundle.putString("edadper",intent.getStringExtra("edad").toString())
        bundle.putString("estatuper",intent.getStringExtra("estatura").toString())
        bundle.putString("pesoper",intent.getStringExtra("peso").toString())
        bundle.putString("ubicacionper",intent.getStringExtra("ubicacion").toString())
        bundle.putString("objper",intent.getStringExtra("objetivo").toString())
        bundle.putString("fotoper",intent.getStringExtra("foto").toString())
        
        val frag = HomeFragment()
        frag.arguments = bundle
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.salir -> {
                dialog()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hasta Pronto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                action()
            }
        }
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
       if (binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
           binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
       }else{
             super.onBackPressed()
       }
    }

    private fun action() {
        auth.signOut()
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    private fun dialog(){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Finalizando sesión...")
        progressDialog.setMessage("Hasta pronto")
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        val orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                val defaultPortrait = 0
                val rightLandscape = 90
                val leftLandscape = 270
                when {
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, defaultPortrait) -> {

                    }
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, leftLandscape) -> {
                        
                        binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                    isWithinOrientationRange(orientation, rightLandscape) -> {
                        
                        binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }

            private fun isWithinOrientationRange(
                currentOrientation: Int, targetOrientation: Int, epsilon: Int = 10,
            ): Boolean {
                return currentOrientation > targetOrientation - epsilon
                        && currentOrientation < targetOrientation + epsilon
            }
        }
        orientationEventListener.enable() 
    }
}
```

en mi mainActivity.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".buildus.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bgcolor"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
            android:background="@color/dorado"
            app:itemIconTint="#0a0a0a"
            app:itemTextColor="#0a0a0a"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/top_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_user"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

En caso de que necesiten información adicional. Me puede dejar un comentario

Comment: Cuál es el código y layout que usas?, es importante agregar más información a tu pregunta. Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: agregue parte del codigo y estoy usando constraintLayout para pintarlo.